# Checking if variable exists in Namespace

Tags: python, namespaces, argparse

I'm trying to use the output of my argparse (simple argparse with just 4 positional arguments that each kick of a function depending on the variable that is set to True)

```
Namespace(battery=False, cache=True, health=False, hotspare=False)
```

At the moment I'm trying to figure out how to best ask python to see when one of those variables is set to True; without having to hardcode like I do now:

```
if args.battery is True:
    do_something()
elif args.cache is True:
    do_something_else()
etc ...
```

I'd rather just use one command to check if a variable exists within the namespace and if it's set to True; but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this in an efficient manner.

Comment: `argparse` uses `getattr(namespace, dest)` to check for values. `vars(args)` creates a dictionary.  You could gets keys and values from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If solved my problem with a list comprehension (after using the tip to use vars() ) :

```
l = [ k for (k,v) in args.items() if v ]
```

l is a list of keys in the dict that have a value of 'True'

Answer (score 8):

You can use `hasattr(ns, "battery")` (assume `ns = Namespace(battery=False, cache=True, health=False, hotspare=False)`).

Much cleaner than `vars(ns).get("battery")` I would think.

Answer (score 4):

Answering the title (not the OP detailed question), to check that variable `a` is defined in the `ns` namespace:

```
'a' in vars(ns)
```

Answer (score 3):

[Use `vars()` to convert your namespace to a dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars), then use `dict.get('your key')` which will return your object if it exists, or a `None` when it doesn't.

## Example

#### `my_args.py`

```py
import argparse


_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("A description of your program")

_parser.add_argument("--some-arg", help="foo", action="store_true")
_parser.add_argument("--another-one", type=str)

your_args_dict = vars(_parser.parse_args())

print(your_args_dict.get('some_arg'))
print(your_args_dict.get('another_one'))
print(your_args_dict.get('foo_bar'))
```

#### command line

```
$ python3 my_args.py --some-arg --another-one test

True
test
None
```